# asp.net check box is always false in form post submit to action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form with a check box:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Services", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "stdform", role = "form" }))
{
     <p>
    <label>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.enabled)</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Enabled" id="Enabled" value="@Html.ValueFor(model => model.enabled)" />
    </span>
    <small class="desc">If the service is enabled.</small>
</p>
    <p class="stdformbutton">
    <button class="submit radius2">Submit</button>
    <input type="reset" class="reset radius2" value="Reset Form" />
</p>
 }
```

now when I submit my form to my action method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ServicesViewModelEdit model)
    {
    }
```

my model.enabled is always = false;

Why is this?

Here is my view model:

```
public class ServicesViewModelEdit
{
    //public Service Service { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ServiceTypes ServiceType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String IpAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Port { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public String Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PollInterval { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FailCount { get; set; }

    public bool enabled { get; set; }

    public List<ServiceTypes> ServiceTypes { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

SWhy not use following?:

```
@Html.CheckBox("enabled", new { @style = "margin: 3px 10px 0;" })
```

This is working fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not binding the value of the checkbox to the `enabled` property in your model so this property is just being set to the default value. Uppercase the first letter of the `enabled` property to `Enabled` in your viewmodel so it matches the `name` attribute of your checkbox input and it should work.

Comment: Changed it to capital and it is still false,  When I ticked the check box.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative; you can use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.enabled)` aswell, which would be much easy to use and read as you already did for *Label*

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the model to the view again in post, so change the View in post to this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ServicesViewModelEdit model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: That part is irrelevant to ths question as I am breaking on the start of the function where I receive my model. and the model.Enabled is false when I selected the check box in the form.